# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [request.model.RTPRequest] and content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rest

I am trying to invoke a POST method on a REST service using Spring Integration's HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.

I have already tried the solution provided on the [Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type and content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894650/could-not-write-request-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-request-type)

Below is my configuration: I have @EnableIntegration and @IntegrationComponentScan annotations on the bean configuration class. I have verified that I have Jackson data-bind jar on the classpath. I am able to get a valid response using POSTMAN.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel rtpRequestChannel() {
    MessageChannel rtpRequestPostOperationRequestChannel = new DirectChannel();
    return rtpRequestPostOperationRequestChannel;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel rtpResponseChannel() {
    MessageChannel rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel = new DirectChannel();
    return rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "rtpRequestChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel rtpResponseChannel) {

    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
            "http://myhost:8080/services/v1-0/request");
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    handler.setOutputChannel(rtpResponseChannel);
    handler.setExpectedResponseType(RTPResponse.class);
    return handler;
}
```

Below is the POJO for service activator endpoint.

```
@Service
public class RTPRequestServiceClient implements IRTPRequestServiceClient {

    @Override
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="rtpRequestChannel")
    public void makeCall(Message<RtpResponse> pr) {
        RtpResponse response = pr.getPayload();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

My request POJO is:

```
public class RTPRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 567078627620810886L;

    private final String id;
    private final String paymentAmountCcy;
    private final String paymentAmount;

    @JsonCreator
    public RTPRequest(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
            @JsonProperty("paymentAmountCcy") String paymentAmountCcy,
            @JsonProperty("paymentAmount") String paymentAmount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.paymentAmountCcy = paymentAmountCcy;
        this.paymentAmount = paymentAmount;
    }

    // getters ommited for brevity

}
```

My responsePOJO is:

```
public class RTPResponse implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3504586520124861349L;

    private String id;
    private String responseId;

    @JsonCreator
    public RTPResponse(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("responseId") String responseId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.responseId = responseId;
    }

    // getters ommited for brevity

}
```

I am sending the request as follows:

```
RTPRequest body = new RTPRequest(....);

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(IntegrationBeanConfiguration.class);
        MessageChannel rtpRequestChannel = (MessageChannel) context.getBean("rtpRequestChannel");
        rtpRequestChannel
        .send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(body)
                .setHeader("accept","application/json")
                .setHeader("Sender","API_GATEWAY")
                .setHeader("ClientId","DIGITAL")
                .build()
            );
```

I am fairly new to Spring integration http. I was assuming that RTPRequest object will be converted into JSON by the virtue of HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler default message converter chain and Jackson data-bind in classpath.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you send your request, you have to explicitly set `contentType` header alongside with that `accept`:

```
.setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
```

To enforce `RestTemplate` to use the mentioned `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Or you can configure `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` only use this `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.