# Error sending MultipartFile to REST API using Spring Boot and Open feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, openfeign

I'm trying to attach a file to send to and endpoint as a `MultipartFile` but I'm getting this exception:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'feign.codec.EncodeException'
//...
Caused by: feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: 
no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] 
and content type [multipart/form-data]
```

My method is:

```
//...
final User user
//...
@Override
DocumentResponse attachDocument(File file, String userId, String documentId) {

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
    String url = "${myProperties.apiUrl}/documents/attach?ts=${timestamp}"
    String digest = myJWT.sign(HttpMethod.POST, url)

    MultipartFile multiFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.xml", 
        new FileInputStream(file))

    DocumentResponse documentResponse = user.attachDocument(multiFile, 
        userId, documentId, timestamp, digest)

    return documentResponse
}
```

My interface is:

```
@FeignClient(name = 'myUser', url = '${apiUrl}', configuration = myConfiguration)
interface User {

    //...

    @PostMapping(value = '/documents/attach', consumes = 'multipart/form-data')
    DocumentResponse attachDocument(@PathVariable('file') MultipartFile multiFile,
                                  @PathVariable('clientId') String userId,
                                  @PathVariable('documentId') String documentId,
                                  @RequestParam('ts') String timestamp,
                                  @RequestParam('digest') String digest)

}
```

And my configuration file is:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
class myConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Retryer feignRetryer(@Value('${feign.client.config.myUser.period}') Long period,
                     @Value('${feign.client.config.myUser.maxInterval}') Long maxInterval,
                     @Value('${feign.client.config.myUser.maxAttempts}') Integer maxAttempts) {
         return new Retryer.Default(period, maxInterval, maxAttempts)
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new ErrorDecoder() {
            @Override
            Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
                if (HttpStatus.OK.value() != response.status()) {
                    FeignException ex = FeignException.errorStatus(methodKey, response)
                    if (response.status() != HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()) {
                        return new RetryableException('getting conflict and retry', new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.SECONDS
                        .toMillis(1)))
                     }
                     return new MyDocumentException()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have tried to add this code to myConfiguration file:

```
@Bean
Encoder encoder() {
    return new FormEncoder()
}
```

But I have another exception:

```
Cannot cast object 'feign.form.FormEncoder@5fa78e0a' 
with class 'feign.form.FormEncoder' to class 'java.beans.Encoder'
```

I'm using Spring boot `'2.0.2.RELEASE'` with:

```
"io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:3.4.1",
"io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:3.4.1",
```

I checked these posts:

[How to send POST request by Spring cloud Feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427639/how-to-send-post-request-by-spring-cloud-feign)

[no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854369/no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response-type)

[Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type and content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894650/could-not-write-request-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-request-type)

[Converting file to multipartfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648549/converting-file-to-multipartfile)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`feign.codec.EncodeException` raised when a problem occurs encoding a message.
I think the `@PathVariable('file') MultipartFile multiFile`, can be converted to a base64 sting and pass it to REST API or add an Encoder to `MultipartFile`

Comment: The API only accept Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="the boundary here" so I think that the problem is how to correct use an Encoder.

Comment: @Javier C did you get answer? if yes please post here.

Comment: @kashiviswanath no sorry, i didn’t found the solution